# Twitter follow button causes console warnings about using dppx

Tags: twitter, twitter-follow

I've added a Twitter **Follow button** to my site, using Twitter's [instructions](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/follow-button)
But in the Chrome console I see this warning:

```
Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is unavoidable in Chrome, as it tries to inform you of what it thinks might be an issue with the tweet button. It's not even a problem, just a suggestion. My solution to the annoying console message is to hide the notices in the console by using the following in the filter search with regex checked:

```
^(?!Consider using 'dppx')
```

This will hide any notices that start with that sentence. At the top of the console tab there is a Filter button next to the Clear Console Log button, if you don't already have it open. You can also filter by message type, this notice comes up under 'debug'.